# How to dispatch two actions, the second after the first is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

The application is like this:

- `actionGetData` - it dispatches an API get request that retrieves some data and shows it in the application. first time it is dispatched in the main component
- `actionToggle` - there is a toggle button in the app, when the button is clicked, it modifies a value from the data showed above, sending a PUT request to the server

The problem is that the data doesn't get updated on the screen, so I assume that we need to call again `actionGetData`.

I assume that it should be done with async await so `actionGetData` waits for `actionToggle` to do the changes. Is this the right way to do it?

This is the code:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const { data } = useSelector((state) => state.myData, shallowEqual);
   
   const toggleValue = (value) => {
      const payload = { resource: !value };
      dispatch(actionToggle(payload));
      dispatch(actionGetData());
   }

  return (
     <div>
      ...
      <button onClick={() => toggleValue(value)}>click me</button>
     </div>
  );
}
```

it doesn't seem to work in this case, tried to make the toggle function async: `const async toggleValue = ...` and add `await` before dispatching actions, still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, async/await only works with Promises - so, that's why it didn't work (because dispatch probably doesn't return a Promise in other words)

Comment: I think you should add [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to your project. Take a look at it.